# Make Windows stop restoring my session

Tags: windows-10, session-restore

It seems like it was about the time of the Windows 10 Fall Creators update that my computer started restoring my session every time I rebooted, restarting my web browser tabs and other programs that may have been running when I shut down, which I don't want, and can't figure out how to turn off.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? When my computer starts, I want it fresh and clean, not trying to pick up on all sorts of random things I was doing last time.

Comment: Welcome to the club that starts to hate Microsoft for making really bad decisions. Can't be turned off, and it bothers me a lot as I have to systematically close 2 new word documents on every startup, which is every day. No script or hack stops it either and I can't uninstall Word either. Maybe I should reinstall windows and not upgrade.

Comment: @LPChip You can only defer 1709 for 4 months.  Eventually, the next feature update will have to be installed, and this behavior will exist in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "old" shutdown dialog (info from [Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-auto-reopen-programs-restart-windows-10/)):

> 1. Minimize all programs by pressing WinKey + M.
> 2. Click on the Desktop to set the focus on it.
> 3. Press Alt + F4 to display the classic “Shut Down Windows” dialog
> 4. Select shut down or restart option from the drop-down menu.

[image]

Another ugly way of doing this is apparently to avoid the Windows 10 shutdown "remembrance" functionality by avoiding the Windows 10 "shutdown" button entirely by [creating a script/shortcut that just does an actual shutdown](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-auto-reopen-programs-restart-windows-10/) using the code:

```
shutdown.exe /s /hybrid /t 0
```

The `/hybrid` switch uses Windows 10s fastboot style shutdown.

---

#### The following methods are apparently unrelated to this feature but are here for completeness of testing.

Go to Start -> Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in Options

Towards the bottom of that screen there is an option `Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart`, toggle it off.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

If you have multiple users that use this machine then you may need to go into each user and disable it individually.

---

Alternatively there is Cortana has a "Pick up where I left off" feature which might be guilty of this. From [ghacks](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/10/25/block-reopening-of-programs-on-windows-10-start/)

> You can configure the feature in the following way:
>
> 1. Tap on the Windows-key.
> 2. Type something, and select the Notebook entry on the left sidebar menu. You can click on the three horizontal lines to display menu
>    names.
> 3. You need to allow Cortana to personalize the experience.
> 4. Then, you may select "Pick Up where I left off" from the settings and toggle the feature on or off.

Comment: You are aware this doesn't actually work?

Comment: I've seen several things stating that it *should*, but none that contest it.  I've not had a reason to disable it personally, but if OP confirms that it doesn't then I will remove my answer.

Comment: Its one of the first things I tried, but still didn't do a thing. I resorted in downloading a script which does it half the time, but even though, I still get 2 empty instances of word on every boot. :(

Comment: Also, your second item looks interesting. Unfortunately I do not have a Notebook entry in the left sidebar. :( Maybe I need to first enable Cortana or something.

Comment: @LPChip I've found some things that suggest that the "pick up where i left off" option is only available if you are using a "US English" language/keyboard which is, quite frankly, braindead.  Seems the only other way is a shutdown script.

Comment: @LPChip I've rearranged my answer to state that those two methods are wrong. According to one source (linked in answer) clicking on the desktop and pressing Alt-F4 will give you the "old" shutdown functionality which doesn't remember programs.

Comment: It's silly that there isn't a setting that makes the regular shutdown work this way, but you certainly seem to have provided a valid answer. When I brought my system back up, nothing old was restarted. Hopefully there will be a better solution someday.

Comment: Yeah, it'd be nice to have some granularity or control over what starts back up at the very least. It can end up with your computer starting up and playing its way through series in Netflix behind the lockscreen. That it is a bit weirdly picky about what it runs again and what it doesn't just adds to the frustration.