# windows 10 launches chrome on start up automatically?

Tags: windows-10, boot, google-chrome, shutdown

I have encounter this problem three months back and I was trying various solutions but none of them seems to work. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

**Problem**: Chrome launches on windows startup automatically.How to prevent it launching on start up?

**What I have tried so far**

1. Complete format of system more than 6 times
2. I have dual boot with ubuntu 16.04 LTS so I removed both OS and installed fresh copy of windows 10 using USB boot
3. There is nothing listed on startup inside Taskmanager related to chrome so I can't disable this.
4. I have modified google service into msconfig but it didn't work either.
5. I have run full system virus and malware checkup, nothing found
6. I have tried one more solution where I had to modify the registry under some user or system control but it didn't work either.
7. I have installed windows 10 from bootable CD but no luck.
8. I have read somewhere this is the new windows 10 feature and I can disable it but it didn't work either.

Now, I have another problem which is when I shutdown my laptop it doesn't shutsdown and fan runs on full speed. It gets stuck in the end of the shutdown process. The screens goes black, hard drive indicator isn't blinking only power LED and WiFi LED is on which is weird. I have to force shutdown every time. It rarely happens when my laptop shutdown completely. Also, in the beginning I though if I leave it for sometime it will shutdown but no. Laptop was running all night on power and fun was running on full speed.

Comment: [use autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and disable Chrome entries. If you can't see it, [disable the option "Pick up where I left off"](https://superuser.com/a/1264531/174557)

Comment: Close chrome before shutting down. Or bypass the session restore functionality in Windows by shutting down using alternative methods: https://superuser.com/questions/1279384/make-windows-stop-restoring-my-session/1279387#1279387

Answer (score 0):

Go to Microsoft website to download clean Windows 10 iso image, then use it or create installation media to clean install system.

Download Chrome from official website and install it, check if there is any task about Chrome in Task Scheduler. Clean boot computer for test.

For shutdown issue, use Windows Performance Toolkit to capture shutdown process, I suspect that there is a third-party software prevent your computer from shutting down.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/